# What is the proper way for a program to open and write to a mapped drive without allowing the computer user to do so?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, windows-networking

I am working with a program designed to record and display user-input data for tracking courses in a training process.  One of the requirements was that we be able to keep a copy of each course's itinerary (in .pdf format) to display alongside the course.  This program is being written in Delphi 7, expected to run on Windows 7 machines.

I've managed to get a remote location set up on the customer's main database (running CentOS 6), as a samba share, to store the files.  However, I'm now running into a usability issue with the handling of the files in question.

The client doesn't want the process to go to a mapped drive; they've had problems in the past with individual users treating the mapped drive another set of programs require as personal drive space.  However, without that, the only method I could come up with for saving/reading back the .pdf files was a direct path to the share (that is, setting the program to copy to/read from `\\server\share\` directly) - which is garnering complaints that it takes too long.

What is the proper way to handle this?  I've had several thoughts on the issue, but I can't determine which path would be the best to follow:

1. I know I could map the drive at the beginning of the program execution, then unmap it at the end, but that leaves it available for the end user to save to while the program is up, or if the program were to crash.
2. The direct 'write-to-share' method, bypassing the need for a mapped drive, as I've said, is considered too slow (probably because it's consistently a bit sluggish to display the files).
3. I don't have the ability to set a group policy on these machines, so I can't hide a drive that way - and I really don't think it's a wise idea for my program to attempt to change the registry on the user's machine, which also lets that out.
4. I considered trying to have the drive opened as a different user, but I'm not sure that helps - after looking at it, I'm thinking (perhaps inaccurately) that it wouldn't be any defense; the end user would still have access to the drive as opened during the use window.

Given that these four options seem to be less than usable, what is the correct way to handle these requirements?

Comment: Drive mappings are user-specific.  You could run the app in its own user account, then it would have its own mappings that other users cannot access.  Otherwise, using a UNC path to the share is your best option. If it is too slow, that is a networking issue, not a coding issue.

Comment: Ask them to backup their claims that access by unc path is slower than mapped drive. That will void all requirements.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work with a samba share.

However you could think about using (secure) ftp or if there is a database just uploading them as a blob.

This way you don't have to expose user credentials to a user.